# Linux Mint error: "Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lst_debian_repo.list (Component)"

Tags: linux-mint, apt

In Linux Mint, when I run the command `sudo apt-get update` I receive the error:

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lst_debian_repo.list (Component)
```

I see the following in that file:

```
deb http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/  main
```

I ask this question because I want to install PHP for Litespeed using the command

```
sudo apt install lsphp72 lsphp72-curl lsphp72-imap lsphp72-mysql lsphp72-intl lsphp72-pgsql lsphp72-sqlite3 lsphp72-tidy lsphp72-snmp
```

But I receive the following error when I run the command above:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lst_debian_repo.list (Component) E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lst_debian_repo.list (Component) E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: The line actually appears to be missing its *distribution* entry rather than its component entry - see for example [wiki.debian.org/SourcesList](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

distro is missing in syntax, edit the entry, for example

"deb http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian jessie main"

then register LiteSpeed GPG key and update the repo

```
sudo xed /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lst_debian_repo.list
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/lst_debian_repo.gpg http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/lst_debian_repo.gpg
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: [Similar question for you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511371/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-lsphp72-depends-libjpeg62-t) if you're interested. Cheers.