# The following packages have unmet dependencies: lsphp72 : Depends: > libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable

Tags: linux-mint, apt, php

I'd like to install PHP for Litespeed on Linux Mint.

After I run: `sudo apt install lsphp72 lsphp72-curl lsphp72-imap lsphp72-mysql lsphp72-intl lsphp72-pgsql lsphp72-sqlite3 lsphp72-tidy lsphp72-snmp` I receive the error:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
>   may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
>   information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  lsphp72 : Depends:
>   libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
>              Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable  lsphp72-intl : Depends: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not
>   installable  lsphp72-tidy : Depends: libtidy-0.99-0 but it is not
>   installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lst_debian_repo.list` contains

```
deb http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian jessie main
```

Why can't I install the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux Mint, the `jessie` repositories aren’t appropriate; assuming you’re running Linux Mint 19 or later, you need to use

```
deb http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian bionic main
```

as your repository.